# NPException in ArrayList? Java

Tags: java

So I keep getting the NPException when running my spell checker. The exception occurs in my "edits" method. So here is the code of the method:

```
    public ArrayList<String> edits (String word){
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    result.add(word.substring(1));
    result.add(word.substring(0, word.length()-1));
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
        result.add(String.valueOf(c) + word);
    }
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
        result.add(word + String.valueOf(c));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++){
        char[] c = word.toCharArray();
        char temp = c[i];
        c[i] = c[i+1];
        c[i+1] = temp;
        String swappedword = new String(c);
        result.add(swappedword);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The error occurs at the 4th line, "result.add(word.substring(1));". I have looked at the related answers, but it didn't help me solve the problem. Help please! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

```
  result.add(word.substring(1));
```

The only possibility to NPE is your `word`  must be `null`.

Please take necessary steps regarding that like checking `null` or informing to `method` caller by throwing `exception`.

Answer (score 1):

> The error occurs at the 4th line, "result.add(word.substring(1));"

Then `word` must be null. `result` clearly isn't. You should look at what's calling this code, and work out why it's passing in a null reference. You might also want to add some validation:

```
public ArrayList<String> edits (String word) {
    if (word == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    ...
}
```

That way it's immediately clear from the stack trace what's wrong. That's assuming you don't *want* to accept a null reference, of course - if you do, then just change the code above to return whatever you want. (I'd personally require `word` to be non-null though.)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the Exception occurs because you don't check for `word` being null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ArrayList<String> edits (String word){
  if (word == null) { 
    return new ArrayList<String>(); // Or null.
  }
  // as before.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you word either `""` or `null`

```
edits("hello");
        edits(""); // fails here java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
        edits(null); // fails here  NullPointerException
```

May be you can add validation in your `edit` method

```
if(word==null || word.isEmpty()){
            return  Collections.emptyList();
        }
```